# Scheduling Tasks Of Authenticated user Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, twitter

I have an application that connects to the twitter api using thujohn/twitter package. I want a schedule that makes sure that at a certain time of the day everyday every user in my application tweets to his timeline. Now the issue with the package is that only an authenticated user can make a api call to twitter. The method is Twitter::postTweet() which will post whatever tweet passed in to the static function to the timeline of the authenticated user. How can I go around it and make sure i can call the method on all my users even if they are not authenticated at the scheduled time.

Here is the [Twitter package where all the logic lies](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter/blob/master/src/Thujohn/Twitter/Twitter.php)

I would appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: Is your application storing their access tokens? It would seem unexpected for your application to post tweets for an unauthenticated user.

Comment: @osowskit yes. I am storing their access tokens